# How to fix P4 "Submitting to multiple branches from one changelist is not allowed"

Tags: perforce

my p4 server declined my submission and output error message. "Submitting to multiple branches from one changelist is not allowed"

Here is my example remote-client mapping of the to-be-submitted files.

```
//depot/projA/Dev/Modules/a/src/moda/file1.cpp //Client/projA/src/moda/file1.cpp
//depot/projA/Dev/Modules/a/src/moda/file2.cpp //Client/projA/src/moda/file2.cpp
//depot/projA/Dev/Modules/a/src/moda/file3.cpp  //Client/projA/src/moda/file3.cpp
//depot/projA/Dev/Modules/b/src/modb/file4.cpp  //Client/projA/src/modb/file4.cpp
//depot/projA/Dev/Modules/c/src/modc/file5.cpp  ///Client/projA/src/modc/file5.cpp
```

How can I submit the changes into single changelist ?

Comment: This sounds like a custom trigger message.  Contact your admin and ask what the trigger considers a "branch" to be -- I would think it would be `//depot/projA/Dev`, but all your files are within that one "branch" and it's rejecting the submit, so your admin's idea of what constitutes a "branch" seems to be different from mine.

Comment: Note that Perforce itself has no built-in idea of what level of the depot hierarchy is a "branch"; branch specs define mappings between branches but there is nothing in Perforce that defines a single "branch" as its own entity, unless you're using streams (which define and enforce certain conventions around branch structure).  Since you're not using streams, any "one branch per submit" rule would have to be enforced by a custom trigger, which can do anything your admin sets it up to do -- so you need to talk to your admin to find out why it's blocking you.